# Bot sending embed message on !help command but it isn't in code, how I can remove it?

Tags: python, command, discord

my python bot for discord sending on !help command but it isn't in code...

How i can remove it?
Maybe it's imported into code idk, it looks like this:
http://prnt.sc/oxqj0s

I have imported this:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game
import os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to get rid of it with the following code:

```
# Imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game
import os

# Create the bot with prefix '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
# Remove the 'help' command
client.remove_command('help')
```

The Discord bot automatically creates a 'help' command at startup. When you then call the help command from the but by typing '!help' (because I set-up the bot with command prefix '!'), it loads the built in help command. The code 'client.remove_command('help')' removes the help command from the bot 'client'.